# What was the reason behind no more new episodes for Tom and Jerry?

Tags: tom-and-jerry

What happened to the most loved cartoon Tom & Jerry, why did the production of new episodes stop suddenly? Does anyone know the real reason?

Comment: Do you mean in 2008, 1994, 1982, 1977, 1967, 1962, or 1958?

Comment: Don't forget the constant movies.

Answer (score 3):

It didn't stop. A [new series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tom_and_Jerry_Show_(2014_TV_series)) premiered in 2014, with a second season released **this year**:

> The Tom and Jerry Show is a 2014 American animated television series
>   produced by Warner Bros. Animation and Renegade Animation, based on
>   the Tom and Jerry characters and theatrical cartoon series created by
>   William Hanna and Joseph Barbera in 1940. It had its world premiere on
>   the Canadian channel Teletoon on March 1, 2014, and premiered on
>   Cartoon Network in the United States on April 9, 2014.
>
> Season 2 premiered on February 6, 2016.